# How to delete Xbox Music saved for offline listening from the Xbox Music App

Tags: windows-8.1, xbox-music

I can't find out how to delete Xbox Music saved for offline listening from the App.
If I press the trashcan button in the Xbox Music App the album will be deleted from my collection (offline and online). Is there a way to delete selected albums from the offline cache?

Answer (score 0):

Delete it from the "Xbox Music" folder in your accounts "Music" folder.

Comment: As written, your post doesn't seem to provide enough useful information to justify a full answer. Can you expand it on a bit?